# Trying to filter image by category in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to filter an image through a category. It works but not the way I want it to. Here are how my models are setup:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Cover', 'Cover'),    
    ('Scan', 'Scan'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    contributor = models.ManyToManyField(Contributor, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']


class Issue(models.Model):

    ...

    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="images_inc", blank=True, null=True)

    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s #%s' % (self.title, self.number)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/issues/%s" % self.slug     
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
```

Views.py:

```
def issue(request, issue_slug):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, slug=issue_slug)
    cover = Image.objects.filter(category='Cover')
    scan = Image.objects.filter(category='Scan')
    return render_to_response('comics/issue_detail.html', {'issue': issue, 'cover': cover, 'scan': scan}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am trying to filter it by Cover or Scan, as you can see, but when I put this into my template:

```
{{ cover }} or {{ scan }}
```

It returns:

```
<Image: Astonishing X-Men 1 Cover A>] [<Image: Astonishing X-Men 1, teamshot>]
```

I need it to return the image URL, obviously. Adding {{ cover.url }} doesn't work.

Oh, and I just realized it does not display the specific image that is in the issue. It displays ALL images that categorized as either Scan or Cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, you're returning all the images, even the ones that aren't associated with your chosen comic issue. I'm assuming you want the ones for the selected issue. You probably want to do this instead:

```
def issue(request, issue_slug):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, slug=issue_slug)
    try:
        cover = issue.images_inc.filter(category='Cover')[0]
    except IndexError:
        cover = None
    try:
        scan = issue.images_inc.filter(category='Scan')[0]
    except IndexError:
        scan = None
    return render_to_response('comics/issue_detail.html', {'issue': issue, 'cover': cover, 'scan': scan}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then, in the template:

```
{% if cover.image %}
    <img src="{{ cover.image.url }}" alt="{{ cover.image.title }}" />
{% endif %}

{% if scan.image %}
    <img src="{{ scan.image.url }}" alt="{{ scan.image.title }}" />
{% endif %}
```

## Update

If you do want more than one cover or scan, then you don't want to get only the first item. And really, you should probably just move this logic to `models.py` to avoid possible code duplication.

Something like this would be better:

```
# models.py


class Issue(models.Model):
    ...
    def scans(self):
        return self.images.filter(category='Scan')

    def covers(self):
        return self.images.filter(category='Cover')

# views.py

def issue(request, issue_slug):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, slug=issue_slug)
    return render_to_response('comics/issue_detail.html', {'issue': issue }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then, in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for cover in issue.covers %}
    <li><img src="{{ cover.image.url }}" alt="{{ cover.image.title }}" /></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No cover</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
{% for scan in issue.scans %}
    <li><img src="{{ scan.image.url }}" alt="{{ scan.image.title }}" /></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No scans</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, great. Thanks a lot. The only problem I'm running into -- Sometimes, there are more than one covers and more than one scans -- definitely more than one scans. How would I go about this in the views? I removed the [0] to them, but that just came up with a display of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

filter always returns the list of matches in an array.

If you just want the first match, you could do something like this

```
 cover = issue.images.filter(category='Cover')[:1][0]
 scan = issue.images.filter(category='Scan')[:1][0]
```

But that will throw an exception if there is no match, so maybe better to wrap in in a try except such as

```
try:
     cover = issue.images.filter(category='Cover')[:1][0]
except:
     cover = None
```

In the template, since cover and scan represent image objects, you can get the url with this syntax:

```
{{ cover.image.url }} or {{ scan.image.url }}
```

The alternative if you want to see all of the images is to load covers and scans (plural) and check to see if they are non empty in your template. There is no need to except for the index error here, and it is much simpler.

In this case you would do:

```
 covers = issue.images.filter((category='Cover'))
```

And then in the template:

```
{% if covers %}
    {% for cover in covers %}
          {{cover.image.url}} - {{cover.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It shows up as 'Astonishing X-Men 1 Cover A' now, but I _need_ it to show the URL of the image, not the text, so that I can put it into HTML. Thanks. Again, adding {{ cover.url}} does not work.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom Gruner. Now, there's usually more than one scan and sometimes more than one cover -- right now, it's set so that it display one. I'd need it to display all the images, as I said below to the other dude. How would I go about this?